# How to add and retrieve data from an intent in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I was trying to implement push notifications in android and below is my `receiver` code

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("skipList", true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                ctx, 0, myIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(intent.getExtras().getString("subject"))
                        .setContentText(intent.getExtras().getString("cover"))
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

So from the above code i was adding the data `skipList = True` to intent `myIntent`

I just want to retrieve this data in my `MainActivity.java` file as below

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent iin= getIntent();
            Log.v("<<<<<<<<<<<<iiiiiiiii>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",iin.toString());
            Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
            Log.v("<<<<<<<<<<<<bbbbbbbb>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",b.toString());
            String wow = b.getString("skipList");
            Log.v("<<<<<<<<<<<<wowowowoow>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",wow.toString());
}
```

But i was unable to get the data from the intent what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: you enter a `boolean` value but expect a `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using putExtra with a boolean parameter, but you are retrieving it as a String.
You need to get it using the  `getBooleanExtra()` method.
Just replace this line:

```
String wow = b.getString("skipList");
```

with this:

```
boolean wow = b.getBooleanExtra("skipList");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `boolean` in your `putExtra` and try to retrieve it as a String.

I think [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) tutorial might be useful for you to gain some more knowledge about what you can do with intents

Answer (score 0):

You are passing boolean value so you should read boolean to
use following code

```
getIntent().getBooleanExtra("skipList", defaultValue);
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In code your passing boolean data through intent,but getting it as a string:
 try like this,

```
   boolean isSkipList = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("skipList");
```

(or)

replace below line:

```
  String wow = b.getString("skiplist");
```

with this line:

```
  boolean wow = b.getBoolean("skiplist");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write

```
 boolean wow = b.getBooleanExtras("skipList");
```

or

```
 myIntent.putExtra("skipList", "true");
```

Comment: as  

       myIntent.putExtra("skipList", true);  
put boolean value with intent, so you have to get boolean in activity...so, for that you have to use b.getBooleanExtras("skipList");

or you can change myIntent.putExtra("skipList", true); to myIntent.putExtra("skipList", "true");
it also solve the problem. Since in activity getString("skipList"); is used.